# Xcode error: failed to launch [directory] - invalid host string: 'localhost'

Tags: xcode

I'm trying to run a C++ project, but I get this "invalid host string: localhost" error.

here is my /ect/hosts file:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 
fe80::1%lo0     localhost
```

Even though, I'm still getting the error. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem.

I have found these solutions online that worked for other people, maybe it will work for you.

Link: 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1896148

https://superuser.com/questions/354902/etc-hosts-getting-reset-in-lion/379560#379560

If anyone else has another other suggestions, I am all ears too because I am still facing this exact same issue.

---

Edit:

I found my solution to the issue. My host file was saved as a .rtf file instead of .txt format. After I made the correction, everything worked. Maybe this will help you. Good luck!

Comment: You should briefly explain what the links mention so your answer is still useful if the links go down